# Do we say "some tiny bits of yogurt or ice cream" "drops"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Some food such as ice cream, yogurt, smoothies etc is in form "a semi-liquid". It is not water but not frozen. It is in the middle.

When eating yogurt, sometimes some tiny bits of yogurt, ice cream, smoothies etc fall off.

Can we call those bits "**drops**", for example, "**Eat over the box to let it catch yogurt drops falling off**!"?

Comment: Drops, or more likely **blobs** if it is a thick substance.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHarvey that "blobs" or "globs" is the word I'd use. I also might just say "a bit" like "oh no, I got a bit of yogurt on my shirt!"

Comment: Definitely not "drops", which to me feels like it's for water only, or maybe clear fluids. "Drips" is what I say: "Oh! I've got ice cream drips all over my shorts."